# @keyframes will not work with a div inside a div

Tags: css, css-animations

I am using @keyframes for the first time, but I can't get it to work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

If I put the animation on the .scroll_down div, it animates, but I want the div inside it to animate. Is there some reason why I can't do that?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container_first">
    <div class="scroll-down">
      <div id="arrow">&#8681;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.scroll-down {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 110px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 6;
}

#arrow {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  animation: bounce 1.2s linear infinite;
}

#arrow { padding-top: 0px; }
@keyframes bounce {
    0%   {top: 10px;}
    25%  {top: 15px;}
    75%  {top: 20px;}
    100% {top: 25px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `#arrow` position relative.

http://jsfiddle.net/myvvwb4m/

```
#arrow {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  animation: bounce 1.2s linear infinite;
}
```

Property `top` does not apply to statically positioned elements.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!!